# Freeze arrays and hashes by default?

Tags: ruby, constants, freeze

Just wondering if something like:

`# frozen_string_literal: true`

exists but for Array and Hash?

The goal is not having to `.freeze` every single of those within the same globals file.

Comment: Something else worth noting is that if you use a code linter, it may support an **auto-correction** feature to fix concerns like this. For example, [`rubocop` has a rule for this](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/MutableConstant), so auto-correcting a file with automatically `freeze` each constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to handle it without using another gem using only vscode and rubocop :

1. Install the rubocop extension on vscode
2. Open your `.vscode/settings.json`
3. Append those rules :

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 5000,
  "ruby.format": "rubocop"
}
```

4. save
5. enjoy

Thanks to Tom Lord for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any library that monkey patches default ruby classes like `Array` or `Hash`. But I found an interesting gem [immutable-ruby](https://github.com/immutable-ruby/immutable-ruby) that may fit your needs

Simple example

```rb
require "immutable/hash"

person = Immutable::Hash[name: "Simon", gender: :male]
# => Immutable::Hash[:name => "Simon", :gender => :male]
```

and you cannot just modify values of it, cause it is immutable. You can perform some actions on that hash, but new copy will be returned to you

```rb
friend = person.put(:name, "James") # => Immutable::Hash[:name => "James", :gender => :male]
person                              # => Immutable::Hash[:name => "Simon", :gender => :male]
friend[:name]                       # => "James"
person[:name]                       # => "Simon"
```

Comment: That's worth considering. I'll give a it a try thanks.